# Error while removing canonical signature from kernal file using pesign tool “pesign: in-place file editing is not yet supported”

Tags: kernel

I want to remove the canonical signature from the Linux kernel file. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 and I am using `pesign` tool to remove the signature from the Linux kernel vmlinuz-5.0.0-36-generic.

But when I execute this command to remove signature, I get an error.

command:

```
sudo pesign -f -r -i vmlinuz-5.0.0-36-generic  -o vmlinuz-5.0.0-36-generic

pesign: in-place file editing is not yet supported
```

If I change the output file name, I am getting different error command :

```
sudo pesign -f -r -i vmlinuz-5.0.0-36-generic -o vmlinuz-5.0.0-36-generic-temp

Invalid signature number -1. Must be between 0 and 0.
```

How can I resolve this error?, or suggest any other Linux tools for removing Canonical signature from kernel file?

Comment: Use a different filename for the output and specify `--signature-number=0` (this is what `man pesign` tells me anyway).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.